# How to get an index position of a char in the String array

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

How to get an index position of a char `c` in the array `chars`?.

```
public static final String[] chars = new String[]{"A","B","C","D","E","F"};
String c = "E";

// the answer is 4.
```

Comment: If your array is sorted, you can use `Arrays.binarySearch()`.

Comment: And if it's not, just use `Arrays.asList(chars).indexOf(c)`

Comment: @Florent Bayle: Yes, it's sorted. Could you please post an example?

Comment: is it an option to use a Set or List?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution, hope this helps you

```
    String[] src = new String[]{"A","B","C","D","E","F"};
    int biggerWher = Arrays.asList(src).indexOf("E");
    System.out.println(biggerWher);
```

Answer (score 4):

If your array is sorted, you can use

> Arrays.binarySearch()

```
int answer = Arrays.binarySearch(chars, c);
return answer;
```

as was mentioned. Otherwise use a for loop.

```
for (int i=0; i<chars.length; ++i) {
   if (s[i].equals(c)) {
        return i;
   }
}
```

Comment: looks like a solution